# Question someone

Tags: grammar

Please look at the following

Source:  http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-international/nirmala-questions-rich-nations/article8545194.ece

Nirmala ***questions*** rich nations.

This is a headline of an article from a newspaper, the link to the article I have quoted.

After reading the article, I didn't understand how "***questions***" is used. I want to know in what sense question is being used. Does it mean she expressed doubts? Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: It  means to ask questions of, particularly in an inquiry into possible transgression.

Comment: Thank you deadrat sir. But after reading the article, I couldn't find a single question being asked. Could you please read that small article and tell me if the usage of question is correct or not?

Thank you.

Comment: @policewala I think this question is better asked on our sister site dedicated to helping people learn English as a foreign language, [ELL.se]. Try it out, there are some great teachers there.

Comment: The Commerce Minister says that if rich nations don't like Indian economic policy, they call India protectionist, but if those same nations take protectionist actions, they refuse to acknowledge it.  The implied question is "Aren't you rich nations being unfair and hypocritical?"

Comment: yes, she is questioning i.e. challenging/disputing the perceived double standards of other G20 members

Comment: deadrat sir, I need your help with some questions. Will you please come to the private messaging of Englishforums? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, she expressed her doubt.  Although, she didn't just express her doubt, she confronted with her doubt.

To `question` means:

> verb
>   verb: question; 3rd person present: questions; past tense: questioned; past participle: questioned; gerund or present participle: questioning
>   1.
>   ask questions of (someone), especially in an official context.
>   "four men were being questioned about the killings"
>   synonyms:   interrogate, cross-examine, cross-question, quiz, catechize; More
>   **feel or express doubt about; raise objections to**.
>   "members had questioned the cost of the scheme"
>   synonyms:   query, call into question, challenge, dispute, cast aspersions on, doubt, suspect, have suspicions about, have reservations about
>   "she questioned his motives"

Comment: What do you mean by 'confronted with doubt'? Please help! thanks